# Apache Tika Configuration to include space between div's

Tags: html, apache, space, apache-tika, tika-server

I need to know the way to configure Apache Tika.

Right now we are using it to parse our html files and then do a search based on the parsed data obtained from Apache Tika parser.

Issue :
 Apache tika actually merging the data available from different div's and includes not space between them.

For Example : If we have div's like below :

```
<div1>Girish</div><div>Kumar</div>
```

The parsed content would look like

> GirishKumar

but I want it as

> Girish (space) Kumar

How can I configure Apache tika such that after every div it includes a space??

Right now we have installed **Apache Tika Jar** in one of our server and make a call to it to get the response back.

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? The Tika Server via a REST call? Other?

Comment: Making a rest call to the server and port where tika is running.

Comment: Which Tika though - Tika App or Tika Server?

Comment: Through Tika Server

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the most recent version of Apache Tika? And what endpoint are you calling?